# Why `Integer[100] arr;` is invalid, while `Ineger[] arr;` is valid?

Tags: java, arrays

I was trying to allocate an Integer array for 100 items, why this declaration isn't valid in Java?

```
Integer[100] intArr1;  ----- (1)
```

Whereas this is valid:

```
Integer[] intArr;      ----- (2)
```

As (2) is valid, how much memory does it occupy? Can anyone help to explain a bit.

*There are some questions in SO which resemble my question, however they are not the same, and I did look in SO before asking this question.*

Comment: 1. because the Java designers chose another syntax to declare and initialize an array of 100 elements.

Comment: Thanks, but the same syntax (#1) is valid in C++; so in Java they chose not to use this syntax.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said in my comment. Java is not C++. There's no reason for something valid in C++ to also be valid in Java, since they're not the same language. Just as an English word isn't necessarily a French word, too.

Comment: @JBNizet: Thanks so much for your help, makes sense. You have helped me in lot of other question clarifications in past too. Appreciation a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first one isn't valid because that's not proper Java syntax.

The second one occupies 0 memory, as you haven't created an array. Only a reference to an array, with the reference being `null`.

You need a `new Integer[100]` there to actually create the *array object*.

Comment: Some Java implementations implement references as pointers, which *do* occupy memory. No?

Comment: Well of course, but there's no *array* that's using memory in the second example.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing two different things.

One thing is the type of variable. In your case, you want to say "the type of variable intArr is array of Integers", which is this code `Integer[] intArr;`

In variable, which type is array of Integers you can put any array of Integers you like, no matter the size, therefore you cannot pre-defined it.

The second thing is assign to a variable.

```
Integer[] intArr = new Integer[10];
```

Answer (score 1):

To initialise an array with 100 items you write:

`Integer intArr1[] = new Integer[100];`

Your second line of code just declares a variable, there is no size declared.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare an array, you don't give it a length. You only give it a length when you initialise it.

This is just a declaration:

```
int[] myArray;
```

If you want to initialize it with an array of length 100, you do this:

```
myArray = new int[100];
```

An uninitialised array is `null` by default, or inaccessible if it is in a local scope.